# Did Html.RenderAction make it into VS2010/ ASP.NET 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

We are planning to use VS2010 later in the future, but currently working on 2008. Since the RenderAction is still a Future, we want to be sure it will be a "Production Quality" component later, when we do decide to move to VS2010...

Does anybody knows if it made it into VS2010 b2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current plan is for Html.RenderAction() to be moved out of Futures and into the core product as of MVC 2 Beta.  (Plans are always subject to change, obviously.)

**VS2008 SP1:**

MVC 2 Beta will target VS2008 SP1.  When MVC 2 is complete, it will continue to target VS2008 SP1.

**VS2010:**

VS2010 Beta 2 ships with MVC 2 Preview 2, which is an earlier release than MVC 2 Beta and thus does not include Html.RenderAction().  If you need it for this build, you can find it in MVC 2 Preview 2 Futures.  When VS2010 is complete, it will ship with MVC 2 RTM.

**ASP.NET 4 / .NET 4**

MVC 2 is technically an out-of-band release, so even though it will ship with VS2010, it's not part of ASP.NET 4 or .NET 4.  That is, you shouldn't expect System.Web.Mvc.dll to be a part of any .NET 4 installer.  It will be able to be downloaded separately after release.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Asp.Net Mvc v2.0 release candidate (System.Web.Mvc namespace).

Quite high odds that it won't just dissappear. :)

Answer (score 0):

It did make it into MVC Beta, and I saw a Microsoft representative demo it last week - so yes, it is very much alive.

Comment: So its no longer a  'Future'? (in the Microsoft Namespace), they moved it to the System.Web.MVC one?